# graph toolkit teams channel picker is not returning anything in the dropdown

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-toolkit

Teams channel picker is not working as expected. it is empty tried both

```
<mgt-teams-channel-picker/>, <TeamsChannelPicker/>
```

[channel picker image after rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMzGP.png)

**scopes: ["Team.ReadBasic.All","Channel.ReadBasic.All","User.Read", "Calendars.Read","Mail.ReadBasic", "Mail.Read"
,"People.Read", "User.Read.All", "Group.Read.All", "User.ReadBasic.All",'profile'],**

where as i am getting the all the teams with Get component "me/joinedTeams"
[me/joinedTeams response in devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo02L.png)

versions of the mgt components

```
"@microsoft/mgt-components": "^2.3.0",
"@microsoft/mgt-react": "^2.3.0",
```

i have also mentioned the below lines, even this didn't help

```
import {MgtTeamsChannelPicker} from "@microsoft/mgt-components"; MgtTeamsChannelPicker.config.useTeamsBasedScopes = true;
```

could not find any error in the console with respect to channel picker in devtools. where the other components like agenda and get are working fine from "@microsoft/mgt-components": "^2.3.0", "@microsoft/mgt-react": "^2.3.0", this versions

Comment: Presumably you have a <Login /> component on your page?

Comment: Yes, could you please confirm you have followed the doc - [Build a Microsoft Teams tab with the Microsoft Graph Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/build-a-microsoft-teams-tab?tabs=unpkg%2Chtml)

Comment: I am using a simple provider, other components like agenda and get which I have used are working as expected except teams channel picker

Comment: I tried with Login component and  it is working for me. Can you try using login component and check it once?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT - should we provide the delegated or application permissions for the user.read.all,  group.read.all, when we use the login component.
currently trying with login component, but i want that to work with simple provider

Comment: It should be delegated. I will try to repro this again and confirm with you.

Comment: @Hunaid Hanfee-MSFT -
i tried with the login component, it is working, but it is not working with simple provider, 
when i use the <TeansChannelPicker> 
`GraphError.js:26 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scopes')
    at SimpleProvider.getAccessToken (SimpleProvider.js:41)
    at AuthenticationHandler.<anonymous> (AuthenticationHandler.js:50)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at tslib.es6.js:74
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Module.__awaiter (tslib.es6.js:70)`
i hope the scopes for the login and simple provider are same

Comment: We have faced the same issue and raised a bug. The bug is internal and engineer team will look into it.